# Covariant derivative of a function on 2-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We know the 2-sphere is

\begin{equation}
S^{2}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}:\;||x||=1\}
\end{equation}

and its Riemannian metric in spherical coordinates is

\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = d\theta^{2} + \text{sin}^{2}\theta d\varphi^{2}.
\end{equation}

Also, we have

\begin{equation}
g_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \text{sin}^{2}\theta\end{pmatrix}\;\;\text{and}\;\;
g^{ij} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\text{sin}^{2}\theta}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

When we calculate the Laplacian of a function $ f $ defined in $ S^{2} $, we can obtain an expression based on the polar coordinates as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Delta f = \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial r^{2}} + \frac{1}{\text{sin}\;\theta}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\left( \text{sin}\;\theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \right) + \frac{1}{\text{sin}^{2}\theta} \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial \varphi^{2}}.
\end{equation}

We can see that the previous expression is different from the one we have for the Cartesian coordinates.

If we consider a generic differentiable manifold, we know the Laplacian, on a local chart, has the following expression:

\begin{equation}
\Delta f = \nabla^{i}\nabla_{i}f.
\end{equation}

Here we know that $ \nabla_{i}f $ is the covariant derivative of $f$, that is,

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{i}f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}f.
\end{equation}

My question, inspired by the Laplacian expression in spherical coordinates in $ S^{2} $, is: Do the covariant derivatives of differentiable functions on 2-sphere have expressions that depend of $ \theta $ and $ \varphi $?

I think that the covariant derivatives on 2-sphere for differentiable functions are the following:

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\theta}f = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f\;\;\text{and}\;\;\nabla_{\varphi}f = \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}f,
\end{equation}

but when I saw the expression for the Laplacian I wasn't sure about this.

I would like to understand this because I also want to know if the expression for the gradient components of f are as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla^{i}f & =g^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}f \\ &
= g^{\theta \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f + g^{\varphi\varphi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}f\\ &
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f + \frac{1}{\text{sin}^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}f.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but the phrase "on a local chart" is doing some work there. If you change the coordinates, the expression changes, in general. (For the same basic reason, there is no canonical Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold at all.)